# Server-Side eventing between Silverlight and the host .aspx page

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, user-controls

Is it possible to set up a listener in a Silverlight control to listen for events on the hosting aspx web page?  I want to have several Silverlight and ASP.NET user controls hosted in a web page.  I want to fire an event on one user control, sending an event to the host page (it needs to be notified), and then I want to broadcast an event back to all controls (both Silverlight and ASP.NET) on the form.  This this possible to do with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight is a client side technology. It can interact with the DOM and it can listen to DOM events, but it can't interact with the ASP.NET controls or listen to events from them.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is a client-side technology. You are allowed though to call Javascript functions. Having that, you can take advantage of the ASP.NET AJAX to make calls to web methods on the host ASPX page. Even better, you can force a full post-back of the ASPX page from Javascript.

(sorry for the late response. i've just come accross this when looking for something else)